# Using MinGw64 and CodeLite is running my program too slow

Tags: windows, compilation, linker, mingw, codelite

I downloaded the MinGw64 compiler on my external drive D: and set its path on env variables accordingly.
I then proceeded to download the IDE CodeLite on the same D: and was able to create a project using the MinGw64 as the compiler.

When writing a simple Hello World it builds instantanly but then takes about 22 seconds to print the result on the Windows console.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you launching a debugger rather than your executable?

Comment: Does your exe run fine outside of codelite? Can you also try a build without debug info too? And make sure you are running and not debugging.

Comment: im not really sure what what happening, but after a system restart, it's now running in 1 second...Perhaps it was due to the fact that I had just installed the compiler.